# Tracking WPF mouse movements amidst multiple WindowsFormsHost controls

Tags: wpf, mouse, winforms-interop

I have a WPF application that has several WindowsFormsHost controls. I'm trying to track the mouse position inside of my application when it is maximized in full-screen mode. If the user puts the mouse near the top screen, I'd like to display a Window with additional menus.

I can use:

- Window.PreviewMouseMove
- InputManager.PreProcessInput, or even
- HwndSource.FromHwnd(WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow).Handle).AddHook(...)

to receive move events so long as the mouse doesn't move over a WindowsFormsHost (if the user does this, I do not receive an event). I think the root problem is because WPF uses a separate HWND for each WindowsFormsHost.

Is there a good way to track the mouse movements across my application without having to manually find each WindowsFormsHost and subscribe to its mouse move events? I'd also like to avoid a global Windows mouse listener if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a good solution besides using a global mouse hook as outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) along with a function like [Visual.PointFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointfromscreen.aspx) to translate the global screen coordinate to an application local coordinate.